# The logo I have made in Illustrator changes when I save to PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, pdf

I have made a logo in Illustrator. It is a very simple text logo where I have created outlines to turn it into a Vector. I also have made some small adjustments with overlays to remove part of the text (see picture). When I zoom in everything is perfect the way I want it to be, but when I save it as a PDF it suddently changes my design and make certain lines thicker and parts of the logo blurry.

Why is that ? I just want a clean logo that I can resize and use for different purposes.

In the second picture you can see that the I is thicker that the other letters but it is not that way in the first photo which is a screenshot of the illustrator file.

[image: Original logo]

[image: PDF file]

Comment: Its either bad antialiasing (Conflation, or accenuating verticals) , hinting, or aliasing.

Answer (score 2):

Thin lines in vector logos will not look good on computer monitors when scaling them smaller or when zooming out. The reason for this is that all images will have to be rendered as pixels on a screen. This is why you shouldn't design logos with very thin lines for use on computing devices if you intend to make them smaller.

You have some choices to make. Either leave the design it as it is, and live with it, and avoid small sizes. Or increase the thickness of the lines, so that it looks good at a small size.  There is absolutely no reason why you can't have two versions of the same logo, one for larger sizes/print, and one for smaller sizes on-screen.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this hundreds of times. The thick letter "I" is because either:

1. it is a stroke (not a fill) in Illustrator. You need to convert
   that to outlines (or expand fille/stroke); or
2. the vector shape is not a closed path. You can tell if an object is not a closed path with the open-arrow tool (select an anchor and try moving it).

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Change zoom. You will notice that the blurriness change and the thickness of I get lost.

It's all due to two things.
 First: Reader usually thickens I (big I) or l (small L) letter so they will be visible.
 Second: Blurriness is due to difference between vector line being "not pixel compatible". The line border fall in the middle of pixel. And because that's not how pixel work the blackness of line and whiteness of background create those gray pixels.  That's why your logo should be prepared for screen.